# Interpreting Seasonality in Time Series

Tags: time-series

I have a discrete time series covering 49 quarters between January 2007 and March 2019, which I am trying to analyse. Before undertaking various forms of analysis I wanted to check for the existence of seasonality and have tried to methods for such in R. In the first I used the WO function (Webel and Ollech) from the seastests package, which informed me that the data did not display seasonality.

```
library(seastests)
summary(wo(tt))

> summary(wo(tt))
Test used:  WO 
Test statistic:  0
P-value:  0.8174965 0.5785041 0.2495668
The WO - test does not identify  seasonality
```

However, I wanted to check such again and used the decompose function, from which I got the below, which would appear to suggest a seasonal component. Can anyone advise if;

[image]

1. I am reading the decomposed data correctly?
   AND
2. Why there is such disagreement between decompose and the seastest results?

Answer (score 0):

The decompose function is a simple function that basically estimates the (moving) period average. The volatility of your time series increases strongly in the last years. Thus the averages may pick up on some random increases. Also, the seasonal component that you obtain using the decompose() function will basically always look seasonal.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- ts(rnorm(80), frequency=4)
seastests::wo(x)
plot(decompose(x))
```

[image]

Therefore, seasonality tests are preferable to assessing whether a time series really is seasonal.
Still, if you have information that the data generating process has changed, you may want to use the test on the last few years of observations.